# Java selenium - how to implement ThreadLocal<WebDriver> in page factory pattern framework?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Could you tell me how to implement `static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>` to enable parallel testing possible ?

This is my base Page where webDriver is initialized

```
public class Page {

@Getter @Setter
public static WebDriver driver;

public Page(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

}
```

This is my step def class:

```
import static utils.Page.driver;

public class LandingPageStepDefs {

    private LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage(driver);
   
    @And("Customer does something")
    public void customerDoesSomething() {
        landingPage.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This is my page object class

```
public class LandingPage extends Page {

    @FindBy(xpath = "this is xpath")
    private WebElement pageWebElement;

}

public LandingPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public void doSomething() {
    pageWebElement.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

A `DriverFactory` object that is responsible for allowing page objects access the driver object

```java
import java.util.Optional;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class DriverFactory {

  private static final ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();

  static void set(WebDriver driver) {
    webDriver.set(driver);
  }

  public static WebDriver get() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(webDriver.get())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Driver is NOT initialised"));
  }

  static void remove() {
    webDriver.remove();
    webDriver.set(null);
  }
}
```

Here are the setup and teardown related classes that manage the webdriver lifecycle management

```java
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Setup {

  @Before
  public void setWebDriver() {
    WebDriver localDriver;

    String browser = System.getProperty("browser", "chrome");
    switch (browser) {
      case "chrome":
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("['start-maximized']");
        localDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        break;
      case "firefox":
        localDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        localDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Browser \"" + browser + "\" isn't supported.");
    }
    DriverFactory.set(localDriver);
  }
}
```

```java
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class TearDown {

  @After
  public void quitDriver(Scenario scenario) {
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.get();
    try {
      if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        saveScreenshotsForScenario(driver, scenario);
      }
      driver.quit();
    } finally {
      DriverFactory.remove();
    }
  }

  private void saveScreenshotsForScenario(WebDriver driver, Scenario scenario) {
    byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
        .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", "screenshot");
  }
}
```

Here's the base class of all the page objects

```java
import driver.DriverFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class BasePage {

    public BasePage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.get(), this);
    }

    public WebDriver driver() {
        return DriverFactory.get();
    }
}
```

Here's how a sample child class would look like

```java
public class HomePage extends BasePage {

  private static final String HOME_PAGE_URL = "https://www.google.";

  @FindBy(xpath = "//img[contains(@src,'/images/branding/googlelogo')]")
  private WebElement logo;

  @FindBy(xpath = "//textarea[@title='Search']")
  private WebElement searchInput;

// rest of the code omitted for brevity

}
```

[The official documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/?lang=java#testng) can be followed for specific instructions on parallelism support in cucumber

Following are the maven dependencies that I used for this sample

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>7.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.12.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**EDIT:**

Lastly here's how a test class would look like, which would combine all of these along with the feature file and the step definitions (These have been intentionally excluded)

```java
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/com/automatedtest/sample/Home_page.feature"},
    plugin = {"pretty",
        "json:target/cucumber_json_reports/home-page.json",
        "html:target/home-page-html"},
    glue = {"com.automatedtest.sample.infrastructure.driver",
        "com.automatedtest.sample.homepage"})
public class HomePageTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

  @Override
  @DataProvider(parallel = true)
  public Object[][] scenarios() {
    return super.scenarios();
  }
}
```

Here in `@CucumberOptions`:

- `features` - represents the location of the feature files that this test class represents
- `glue` - represents the packages which contains your step definitions
- `plugin` - captures the list of formatters that will render the report. We are essentially configuring our formatter such that:

  - we get a pretty printed output on the console (`pretty`),
  - a JSON
    report gets generated in `target/cucumber_json_reports` with its name
    as `home-page.json`
  - a html report gets generated in `target` directory with its name as `home-page-html`